# continuous integration pain points

Tags: github, jenkins, continuous-integration, pull-request

Recently my fledgling team (just two devs) attempted to implement continuous delivery practices as described by Jez Humble.

That is we ditched feature branches and pull requests (in git) and aimed to commit to the mainline branch every day at least.

We have a comprehensive unit and functional test suite for both the front and back end which is triggered automatically by Jenkins, when pushing to git.

We configured a feature switching app and resolved to use it for longer running features.

However, we encountered several problems and I'm curious to get a perspective from people who are successfully using this approach.

1. **Delays due to Vetting/ Manual QA process**
   often tasks were small enough that we didn't think they warranted configuring feature switching, e.g. adding an extra field to a form, or changing some field labels.  However, for various reasons that ticket would become blocked (e.g. some unforeseen aspect of the task needing UX input).

   This would mean mainline ended up in a compromised state whilst we waited for external dependencies to unblock the task. Often we'd be saying "we can't deploy anything until Thursday, as that's when we can get an IA review"

   The answer here is probably a much tighter vetting of which tasks are started.  However, it was often difficult to completely anticipate every potential blocker. Maybe if a task becomes blocked additional dev should be done to add a feature switch, or revert the commits?  Tricky situation.
2. **Issues with code review during integration on mainline branch**

   Branches and pull requests give a nice breakdown of changes made on a single task.  However, attempting CD we ended up with a mish-mash of unrelated commits on mainline, and the code reviewer having to somehow piece together commits that related to the task he was reviewing. And often there'd be a number of additional minor bug fixes, changes in response to review type commits at the end of a task.  Essentially we couldn't figure out a clean way to code review work with this set up.
3. **Generic code review issues**

   We used phabricator for a bit to do post-commit code reviews, but found it was flagging every single commit (some very minor) for code review, rather than showing us a list of changes per individual dev task. So it made reviewing the code onerous compared to git pull requests.  Is there a better way?

We've now reverted back to short lived feature branching in git and raising pull requests to initiate code review and it's a nice set up, but if we could fix the issues we're having with non-feature branching CD, then we'd like to re-attempt that approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Could you automate the vetting process and/or run it before you integrate. If you automate the vetting process, for ex adding a form/button etc, you just need a suite of test to run post integration to validate that your mainline is not broken
2. You need to code review before integration i.e on the pull request . If issues are caught during a code review and fixed, the pull request is updated and the mainline is not messed.
3. Code review tools are very specific to a group of developers and the team needs.I suggest you play with a few code review tools to see which one suits your needs

Based on most of your questions, I would recommend running all your Vetting/code review etc before you merge.(You can do it in increments if the process is too cumbersome) and running an automated suite of tests for all the stuff that you want to do post integration.

If the process setup that you have in your team is too complicated to be finished in a day and can have multiple iterations , then it is worthwilefor you to evaluate a modified version of [gitflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow/) than a fork based CI model

Answer (score 0):

If you use feature branches to work on tasks when you finish with a task you can either merge it back to the integration branch or create a pull request for the merge back to the integration branch.

In both case you get a merge commit, a summary of every change you made on the feature branch.

Do you need something more than this?

Comment: I'm talking about doing continuous delivery without feature branching or "gating of the master" branch.  Seems fairly radical, but watching any talks by Jez Humble (a tech architect for Thought Works) there's clearly a number of positives to be had from working this way, if we can work through the issues we're having.